# Adding reference to an assembly in a .aspx.cs (web site project) file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have to add a reference to a .dll so that I could make use of it's business logic in my web-page. I've created a web site (project) in visual studio. And if I simply add a reference to the .dll by normal ways, I could see the .dll in the References part of my solution explorer. When I add the namespace of the .dll using the `using` keyword, I get the squiggly lines reporting that the "assembly could not be found". I've checked the 'debug' folder of my project and I could see the .dll copied from it's original location by visual studio. So everything looks fine.

Should I need to do anything extra to add reference in  web-site type projects? Basically I need this reference in a code-back file. i.e the .aspx.cs file for the .aspx web page so that I could work out some business logic for the web-page.

Comment: just try to instantiate some class or method from within that DLL. You should get a hint from Visual Studio asking you to import the correct namespace

Comment: @Thousand Nope..the intellisence isn't showing. It simply says that an assembly reference might be missing. And the minute I add the reference manually(in the code i.e with the `using` keyword), red squiggly lines appear under the namespace.

Comment: check .Net versions of project and referenced assembly

Comment: @devio They were different. Now I've made both the .Net versions to be of 3.0. But yet the same problem persists.

Comment: @devio But if I change both to version 3.5, for some weird reason it works. I can accept yours as an answer :) thanks!